# GKE Kubernetes external domain provider

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I built simple cluster in GKE with two services using this tutorial
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app

After finishing that I'm able to access my service using external IP address. So I bought domain for using this  IP address. After setup  A record in DNS settings to that IP address, domain doesn't work, it still loads  and then show ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. Do I need to do something in google console, or how I  can make this IP public and accessed through domain?

Comment: can you provide more information about the record you have created and you attached it to your cluster?

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let community know about the usefulness, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip), which describes steps you need to take to configure domain names with static IP.

There are steps that you need to cover:

1. Go to `NETWORKING` section at GCP console, than `VPC Network` -> `External IP addresses` to ensure that you are running static IP address, not ephemeral one.
2. Go to `Network services` -> `Cloud DNS`. You need to create `DNS zone`, where at DNS name line you have to wright your domain name. After creation you will see `Add record set`, where you need to paste your external IP address.

There is also a good tutorial at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXtqqofrhOo) with setting up custom domain on GCP. Let me know if it works for you.